# Tracking daily stats/movement with CSV files

Tags: python, csv

I want to monitor a long ongoing competition. There is a starting date where most people will start, but people can join at any day until the last day. Each day I'm going to get a (csv) file that shows the competitor's rankings of that particular day. All the end-of-day file will have is an ordered number (ranking) and the person's name (I'm computing the points system elsewhere).

I want to be able to 'monitor' who is on an upward trend, who is neutral, and who is losing their position. The end-of-day file won't include the same people every day because new people could add at any time and people can drop out.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Create one 'player list' where instead of moving players around I create a new column each day with their ranking? And then when new players join they get appended to the list with all of the day columns set to 0 except for the join date? And then to see who is on a downwards trend I do a computation for every day? This seems like a good idea to me except the new rankings list I've set up for each day will be formatted according to rank, not name.

I saw this resource but I don't think it can do most of what I'm looking for: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvdiff